# NHibernate 3.3 loquacious mapping when using conventions the id of my entities is not being updated after save. Possible bug?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

The short version:

When I save an entity the id property is not updated when using conventions in NHibernate 3.3

Detailed version:

Entity Id property

```
public virtual Guid GuitarId { get; protected set; }
```

With this mappings my entities are saved in the database correctly but the id's of my entities are not being populated, even when I try to load my entity they are simply ignored....

```
    mapper.BeforeMapClass += (model, type, classCustomizer) =>
    {
        classCustomizer.Id(x =>
        {
            x.Column(type.Name + "Id");
            x.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
        });
    };
```

Trying to get a saved entity, I get populated all the fields of my entity except the Id, I tried to access the id property just in case it were lazy loaded but no luck:

```
var g = session.Get<Guitar>(existingId);
```

If I override the id mapping for an entity I get the id property populated correctly after saving

```
    mapper.Class<Guitar>(map =>
    {
        map.Id(x => x.GuitarId, x =>
        {
            x.Generator(Generators.GuidComb);
        });
    });
```

So the problem is in the `BeforeMapClass` event, any suggestions??

Am I missing anything? or is this a bug?

Comment: Not well versed with fluent nhibernate, but might be something to do with access strategies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your convention-based block does not define which property represents the primary key; only which **database column** it's mapped to, so it is assumed to be a non-mapped id (i.e. NHibernate knows about the Id, and you can get it from NHibernate, but it's not represented in the domain model)

When you map it manually, you are defining the property, and the column by default uses the same name; that why it works.

This additional convention will take care of defining the Id property

```
mapper.IsPersistentId((mi, d) => mi.Name == mi.DeclaringType.Name + "Id");
```

Comment: That makes sense to me, lemme try